# How to create Model for this Json?

Tags: json, swift3, xcode8

I am beginner in iOS swift3. Actually I am facing a problem in creating  my own Model from Json I am getting from an API. My Json has three arrays namely CountryList, CityList and PortList. CountryList has countryID and countryName. CityList has countryId,cityId and cityName. PortList has countryId,cityId and portName. Now,i want display data in a tableView which has country and cities based on country and ports based on city. I want to create a Model which has country and cities in that country and ports in that respective city. I will be very thankful if someone helps me.
Thank you..
Here is the code what I have written so far...

```
struct Country {

var countryId: String!
var countryName: String!

init(countryId: String, countryName: String){
    self.countryId = countryId
    self.countryName = countryName
}}
struct City {

var countryId: String!
var cityId : String!
var cityName: String!

init(countryId: String, cityId: String, cityName: String){
    self.countryId = countryId
    self.cityId = cityId
    self.cityName = cityName

}}
struct Ports {

var countryId: String!
var cityId : String!
var portName: String!

init(countryId: String, cityId: String, portName: String){
    self.countryId = countryId
    self.cityId = cityId
    self.portName = portName

}}
```

I created three structs for holding data that I am getting from Json.
My code in viewController looks like this.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

var countriesList = [Country]()
var citiesList = [City]()
var portsList = [Ports]()

var cities = [String]()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    getData()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()

}

func getData(){

    let url = URL(string: "http://54.186.73.184:8081/api/v0/portlist/search/1")
    var request = URLRequest(url: url!)
    request.httpMethod = "GET"

    let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

        if error == nil{

            do{
                let data = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String: AnyObject]
               // print(data)

                let countriesData = data["country_list"] as!  [[String: AnyObject]]
                //print(countriesData)

                for ids in countriesData{

                    let id = ids["_id"] as! [String: AnyObject]

                    let cId = id["_id"] as! String



                    let country = id["country"] as! String

                    //  self.countries.append(country)


                    let countrydata = Country(countryId: cId, countryName: country)
                    self.countriesList.append(countrydata)



                    for country in self.countriesList{
                        let cId = country.countryId

                        let cityList = self.getAllCities(withCountryId: cId!)


                    }

                }



                let cityData = data["city_list"] as!  [AnyObject]
                for ids in cityData{

                    let id = ids["_id"] as! [String: AnyObject]
                    // print(id)
                    let countryId = id["country_id"] as! String
                    // print(countryId)


                    let cityId = id["_id"] as! String
                    // print(cityId)

                    let city = id["city"] as! String
                    // print(city)





                    let cityData = City(countryId: countryId, cityId: cityId, cityName: city)

                    self.citiesList.append(cityData)
                    //   print(self.citiesList)
            }


               let portData = data["port_list"] as!  [AnyObject]
                for ids in portData{

                    let id = ids["_id"] as! [String: AnyObject]
                    // print(id)

                    let countryId = id["country_id"] as! String
                    //  print(countryId)

                    let cityId = id["city_id"] as! String
                    //  print(cityId)

                    let port = id["ports"] as! String
                    //  print(port)

                    let portData = Ports(countryId: countryId, cityId: cityId, portName: port)
                    self.portsList.append(portData)
                    //  print(self.portsList)

                }

                }catch{

                print(error)
            }
          }
        }
       task.resume()
    }

func getAllCities(withCountryId id: String) -> [AnyObject]{

    // print("citiesList---------\(self.citiesList)")

    for city in self.citiesList{

        if (city.countryId == id){

          self.cities.append(city.cityName)

        }
    }

    return [self.cities as AnyObject]

}}
```

But I am getting empty cities List.
Hope someone finds an idea for creating a Model which meets my requirement.
Thank You..

Comment: What does `print(countriesData)` print? (the commented code)

Comment: Apart from your question here is an advice: **Never ever** declare members / properties of a struct / class as implicit unwrapped optional which are initialized via an `init` method with non-optional parameters. Don't do that. Declare them as non-optional. Remove all exclamation marks.

Comment: countriesData prints Array of countries which are dictionaries..

Comment: fine, thanks for your advice vadian